# hibernate error when hbm2ddl.auto set to update

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

when i set the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value to create i get no errors,
but when i set it to update i get an error.
i need to create the tables and update them so i need the value to be update.
any ideas for what could go wrong?

here is the error:

> 15:55:19,148 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "WebService.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"WebService.war#swap\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: swap] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: swap] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
>       Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"PG_CLASS\" not found; SQL statement:
>   select relname from pg_class where relkind='S' [42102-193]"}}
>   15:55:19,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "WebService.war" (runtime-name : "WebService.war")
>   15:55:19,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
>   15:55:19,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
>   WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."WebService.war#swap": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: swap] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

and here is my persistence xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

```
<class>org.Swap.WebService.Model.User</class>
<class>org.Swap.WebService.Model.BaseEntity</class>

<properties>
        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

        <!-- Database properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> <!-- DB Driver -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/swap" /> <!-- BD Mane -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hidden" /> <!-- DB User -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="hidden" /> <!-- DB Password -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Edit:
if i start the wildfly with

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

then setting it up to update and publishing it will work until i restart wildfly.
can it be a problem with wildfly loading?

EDIT2:
here is the datasouces from my standalone xml:

```
 <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/swap" pool-name="swap" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/swap?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Comment: The error states "Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"PG_CLASS\" not found, do you have enough permissions?

Comment: what do you mean by premmisions?

Comment: On postgres each user can have permissions like update, create and read.

Comment: my user is supseruser with create could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about dialect and driver set.

Your hibernate uses H2 driver with Postgres dialect.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
```

you can see in hibernate logs, what driver and dialect it uses.
Here is fragment showing how hibernate logs should look like:

```
INFO  [Version] - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
INFO  [Environment] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO  [Environment] - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  [MppNamingStrategy] - using naming strategy: MppNamingStrategy
INFO  [Version] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
DEBUG [JdbcServicesImpl] - Driver ->
       name : H2 JDBC Driver
    version : 1.4.196 (2017-06-10)
      major : 1
      minor : 4
DEBUG [JdbcServicesImpl] - JDBC version : 4.0
INFO  [Dialect] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  [Version] - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final
INFO  [SchemaValidator] - HHH000229: Running schema validator
```

You can see in this example that hibernate uses

- H2 JDBC Driver
- org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

In your stacktrace we can see that your hibernate uses postgres dialect (OK), but with H2 driver (bad)

Comment: so what i need to change for it could work? i added the datasources i have in my standalone xml

Comment: Hi, I don't know jboss configuration, but try to remove any H2 driver from configuration and check if now your DataSource uses org.postgresql driver.

Comment: after removing the h2 driver i get a new error:    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.h2",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.h2"

Comment: You should remove also services that need h2, if it is possible. For example datasource "java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" uses h2 driver as I can see in your configuration. Another option to try is to configure DataSource **directly** in JPA xml file to be sure what hibernate will use.

Comment: Anyway, as I pointed, this is not hibernate problem with hbm2dll. This is merely configuration problem as jboss uses DataSource with H2 driver and PostgresSQL dialect at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  przemek hertel  i managed to get it to work.
i remove the h2 from the datasource and driver

```
<datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/swap" pool-name="swap" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/swap?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

and i removed this line:

```
   <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

and now it is working!
thank you all for the help.